# No me funciona el método set en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo

Creé esta clase `Usuario` con un `property` Edad que debería ocupar el método `__setEdad` para cambiar la edad, el que impone que la edad sea siempre mayor o igual a 18.

````
class Usuario(object):

    def __init__(self, edad):
        self.__edad = edad

    def __getEdad(self):
        return self.__edad

    def __setEdad(self, edad):
        # La edad es 18 si es menor de edad```
        if edad < 18:
            self.__edad = 18
        else:
            self.__edad = edad

    # Definir propiedad 'Edad' para acceder a los métodos get y set.
    Edad = property(__getEdad, __setEdad)

u1 = Usuario(12)
# Deberia imprimir 18, la edad mínima
print(u1.Edad)
````

produce:

```
12
```

Cuando debería retornar 18.

Answer (score 7):

El problema primordial que tienes es que no estás usando el descriptor `property` correctamente. La idea de [este descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) es el que puedas obtener (o modificar) un dato de una clase que quieras que esté oculto o protegido, o que requiera alguna validación o procesamiento, pudiendo referirte a él como si se tratase de un atributo cualquiera.

Lo que estás haciendo mal es esto:

```
def __init__(self, edad):
    self.__edad = edad    # <----- Acá
```

Ya que al hacer eso, estás haciendo una asignación a `__edad`, y no a `Edad`, la cual es la referencia que tú quieres que sea la que dispare el métodos `__set__()` del descriptor `property`.

También nota que no es necesario el colocar el doble underscore antes de los miembros de tu clase si no planeas tener una subclase de la misma, lo cual te permita aprovechar el [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). Recuerda que en Python no tenemos modificadores de acceso, por lo cual si lo que deseas es dejar claro que `edad` es un atributo que solo debería ser usado dentro de la clase, basta con que coloques un solo underscore antes del nombre.

Así pues, la manera de hacerlo sería la siguiente.

```
class Usuario:
    def __init__(self, edad):
        self.edad = edad    # <--- Esto disparará el método __set__() del descriptor property

    def _get_edad(self):
        return self._edad

    def _set_edad(self, value):    # El método __set__() del descriptor está asociado a este método
        self._edad = max(18, value)

    edad = property(_get_edad, _set_edad)
```

Con lo cual puedes hacer:

```
>>> u = Usuario(12)
>>> u.edad
18
```

Para más información, recomiendo leer sobre el [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), la cual es la *magia negra* que hace Python tras bastidores al hacer esto.

Comment: +1. Buena respuesta

Comment: Gracias, @CandidMoe No es que la tuya sea incorrecta, para nada, solo que no se estaría aprovechando las cosas que Python provee para esto.

Comment: Bueno, hoy aprendi algo nuevo.

Answer (score 3):

Otra forma de conseguir exactamente lo mismo a lo hecho por @revliscano y cambiando tu ejemplo, es usar `property` como decorador.

```
class Usuario(object):

    def __init__(self, edad):
        self.edad = edad

    @property
    def edad(self):
        return self._edad

    @edad.setter
    def edad(self, edad):
        self._edad = max(18, edad)

u1 = Usuario(12)
print(u1.edad)
```

**Salida:** 18

De esta forma hemos hecho que edad se convierte uen un **instance property** (propiedad de la instancia). Realmente lo que hace es crear un atributo `_edad` que es siempre accedido por nuestro atributo de instancia `edad`.

Dos cosas ha tener en cuenta:

- `_edad` no es un atributo privado, puesto que en Python no existen. De hecho puedes acceder a el mediante `u1._edad`. La barra baja se usa como **convención para indicar al programador** que no se debe acceder a este atributo directamente, si no a traves de su propiedad de instancia.
- `edad` no es un atributo, como hemos dicho es una propiedad de instancia. Esto se puede ver cuando ejecutas `Usuario.__dict__`

**Salida:**

```
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__',
              '__init__': <function __main__.Usuario.__init__(self, edad)>,
              'edad': <property at 0x7f42e80c7d60>,
              '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Usuario' objects>,
              '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Usuario' objects>,
              '__doc__': None})
```

Vemos como `_edad` aun no existe como atributo, puesto que estamos viendo el diccionario de la clase y `edad` es una propiedad.

Si vemos el diccionario de la clase una vez instanciada, vemos que ya si existe el atributo `_edad`. que ha sido creado mediante la propiedad `edad`.

`u1.__dict__`

**Salida:** `{'_edad': 18}`

Internamente la clase `property` lo que hace es:

1. Primero buscar en el diccionario del objeto el atributo
2. Al no encontrarlo, va a buscarlo a la propia clase donde se encuentra con el setter y el getter para ser utilizados.

En particular me encanta esta implementación de Python porque permite crear una clase y refactorizar sus atributos con `@property` haciendo pocos cambios en el código.

Comment: Buen aporte, Alberto. Sí, de hecho el uso de `property` está mucho más extendido en su forma de decorador en lugar de usando el constructor de la clase `property` directamente.